# How to export nginx access log to a socket, instead of a file?

Tags: nginx, logging, influxdb, nginx-config, access-log

I want to push logs, produced by `nginx` to `influxdb`.
To handle this, I have an agent, which can format it, extract some geodata, produce geohash, etc..

The problem is that `nginx` and agent are running in separate `docker` containers, and `nginx` is a producer, that is only capable of writing to filesystem, but `agent` is only capable of reading from network (eg some tcp stream, websocket or http, as it is usually done in webdev)

I dont want to share access.log volume between containers, wasting space, and long-parsing kilometers of logs..

How to make nginx write log directly to some tcp socket?

Answer (score 3):

nginx write log directly to some tcp socket is not safe ,
as socket writing may slowdown or even block nginx

nginx can be configured to [logging to syslog](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/monitoring/logging/#logging-to-syslog)
if the `agent` is capable of reading syslog

```
access_log syslog:server=syslog_server_ip:sys_log_server_port,facility=local7,tag=nginx,severity=info;
```

if you are determined to do custom forwarding , here is another simple but buggy way
configure nginx write to a named pipe, send it out with ncat

```
mkfifo /var/log/nginx/access.log  
ncat  agent_ip agent_port 0</var/log/nginx/access.log
```

this is buggy because ncat must be manually restarted when disconnection occurs
supervisor can help on restarting
but  a few log lines  may lost when they are hold by ncat but do not send out over network

flume is a better tool to do such [log forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422885/using-nginx-to-forward-tracking-data-to-flume)

Comment: Thanks. I've finished up implementing syslog server, which parses nginx output to influxdb format, adds geohash and sends out to influxdb for mapping. And sometimes writing to HDD /var/log/nginx may slow up, on contrast with "writing to locally-deployed app"...

Comment: @xakepp35 Well, you could have simply used [fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org)